# Call specific function within function depending on user input

Tags: python

Question: How to call a different functions within `stat_frac_sales()` based on its argument `stat_requested`?

I want to calculate a financial ratio that will have different numerators (earnings, gross profit, etc...) but always the same denominator (sales). It would look like something like that:

```
def stat_frac_sales(company, input1, input2, stat_requested):
    stat_data =  # call a function here based on the value of stat_requested
    sales = import_sales(company) # Sales function that will not vary

    ratio= stat_data/sales

    return ratio
```

For instance, if `stat_requested = 'FCT'`, then the function `FCT()` should be called.

For example `FCT` and `EBIT` function look like:

```
def FCF(company,  input1)
   ...some code
   return FCF

def EBIT(company, input2)
   ...some different code
   return EBIT
```

So if the user call `FCF` (`stat_data='FCF'`), it would look something like that:

```
def stat_frac_sales(company, input1, input2, stat_requested):
    stat_data = FCF(company, input1) # <-- like so but unclear as to how to make this dynamic, where the function called here changes based on stat_requested
    sales = import_sales(company) # Sales function that will not vary*

    ratio= stat_data/sales

    return ratio
```

Hope this is clear. Any idea on how to do that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry I am not following your question. If you want a user-input then simply just use stat_data = input('enter a earning, gross profit, etc value'), but then you don't need to pass in a stat_data argument into your stat_frac_sales function. Whenever you call your stat_frac_sales function in your code, the user will be prompted with a input

Comment: Realise this was not clear. Hope this is better now. Thanks a lot for your help! Much appreciated

Comment: Your code is clearer now, but I am still not following what the error/problem is? As long as your function are defined above stat_frac_sales, they are fair game to be used downstream by your stat_frac_sales function. Also as long as FCF, EBIT, and import_sales returns a int or float then you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks for your patience PydPiper. I wasn't sure about the best way to dynamically adapt the code depending on what the user sets up for stat_requested.
For instance, if stat_requested=FCF, the code should become  stat_data =FCF(company, start, end, input1).
I thought about implementing a "if, elif" but not sure how this scales if you have 50+ possible ratios.
Would look something like: 
if stat_data =='FCF': 
   stat_data =FCF(company, start, end, input2)
elif stat_data =='EBIT': 
   stat_data =EBIT(company, start, end, input1)
...etc....
Maybe a dictionary might help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh! yeah for sure, you are on the right path with dictionary. I'll type something up in a sec, but for now I think you have a typo in your bottom code def stat_frac_sales(company, input1, input2, stat_data):    I think you mean to say stat_requested instead of stat_data

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: so not sure how to remove the question from [hold] but ill just type the answer in here:
def stat_frac_sales(company, input1, input2, stat_requested):
    funcs = {'FCF': FCF, 'EBIT': EBIT}
    stat_data = funcs[stat_requested](company, input1)
    sales = import_sales(company) # Sales function that will not vary*

    ratio= stat_data/sales

    return ratio

Comment: @PydPiper the question has been removed from the hold queue; you can now post your solution as an answer.